# What Facebook integration best supports Facebook login and Facebook "Like" in Drupal 7?

Tags: facebook, drupal, drupal-7

I have been playing with Drupal for a few days and am hoping to migrate my site to using it.

I was hoping to have Facebook Logins and "Likes" supported for all users, and to hack together something on my own that posts Drupal article summaries onto my own wall with a link.

I specifically want to use Drupal 7 since I figure I may as well learn the most recent release. The one downside with this release so far is that a large number of modules don't have a 7.x release, or at least not a stable one.

Any suggestions on what Facebook module looks best? Currently leaning toward [Drupal for Facebook](http://drupal.org/project/fb) but they don't have a stable release out yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're best off going with Drupal for facebook even though it's not stable. But this is just my 5 cents. Help developers making it a stable and good release by using it and submitting ticket.

cheers, 
Jørgen

Comment: Sounds like this is the best way to go then. I was hestitating to use it since learning the system with something unstable risks making it more confusing. 

Maybe I will look to adding this feature after a week or two of getting Drupal basics down, rather than having it something I want running right away. 

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing with [Janrain](http://www.janrain.com/) and the [Janrain Engage module](http://drupal.org/project/rpx). The free service seems decent enough for a small website and it supports many other sites in addition to Facebook (e.g. Google, Yahoo, Myspace.)

Might be worth a look.. The Drupal 7 release is still in development for this one as well.